# Spy function in react test is not firing

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a controlled component with a form that consists of two radio buttons and a text input. I have a function that is called for onChange event of the text input and have written a test that fires a change event. I expect that the spy function should be called once but the test always fails.

Test

```
test('Update function is called when text entered into searchbox', () => {
    const spy = jest.fn();
    const {getByTestId} = render(<SearchDropdown handleChange={spy}/>);
    expect(getByTestId('searchText').value).toBe("");
    fireEvent.change(getByTestId('searchText'), { target: { value: "23" } });
    expect(getByTestId('searchText').value).toBe("23");
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Component - does not take in any props

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import SearchResults from './SearchResults';

export default class SearchDropdown extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            type: 'Spec',
            number: '',
        }

    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        let name = event.target.name;
        let target = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            [name]: target}
        );
    }

    handleSearch = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.number !== "") {
            console.log("Make request to API");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div data-testid="searchMenu">
                <div className="list-group dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mr-5 text-center">
                    <h5><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch}/> Quick Search</h5>
                    <form className="m-2">
                        <div className="form-group" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <input type="radio" value="Spec" name="type" defaultChecked /> Specification 
                            <input type="radio" value="Claim" name="type" className="ml-2"/> Claim
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Search Number</label>
                            <input type="text" data-testid="searchText" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.number} name="number" className="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <SearchResults />
                    </form>
                    <div className="panel panel-default">
                    </div>
                    <button className="bg-transparent border-0 link">Advanced Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Error Message

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.

          fireEvent.change(getByTestId('searchText'), { target: { value: "23" } });
          expect(getByTestId('searchText').value).toBe("23");
          expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
                     ^
      });

      test('Clicking search brings up results modal', () => {

      at Object.toHaveBeenCalledTimes (src/Tests/SearchDropdown.test.js:18:17)
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly new to React and React Testing Library, but there are a couple of things I noted:

1. In your test you're passing a spy as the value for prop `handleChange` to your component, which it doesn't have; just as you state: "*does not take in any props*".
2. Your component **defines** `handleChange` function which you use an event handler, it doens't get it from a prop.
3. Your `handleChange` function should be passed only as prop to input elements, not a div.
4. You should have one handler per each input instead of calling the same handler for all of them.

That said, in order for your test to provide any value, you should change your *SearchDropdown* component so that it receives the handlers from a parent or you test that firing click/change events on the inputs actually updates the view as expected.
I don't think there's any value in testing if an internal event handler function has been called. 
You're using React Testing Library in your test, but not in the way  it's intended to.
From [React Testing Library Intro](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro):

> The utilities this library provides facilitate querying the DOM in the
>   same way the user would. Finding for elements by their label text
>   (just like a user would), finding links and buttons from their text
>   (like a user would). It also exposes a recommended way to find
>   elements by a data-testid as an "escape hatch" for elements where the
>   text content and label do not make sense or is not practical.